# Parsing data from html based on a string

Tags: jquery, html, parsing, cheerio

I need to extract a particular value from a html page -- the related html content is as below:

```
-html --

<table border=0  cellspacing='1'  cellpadding='0' class="content-denote"     width="965" >
                        <tr height=17><td align=left class="text21"><b>Sensex : 26326.60
                                    [22.40]

                                    <img src="../images/arow_green.jpg" width="14" height="12">




                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Nifty : 7970.05 [14.60]
                                    <img src="../images/arow_green.jpg" width="14" height="12">

-- end of html --
```

The value I need to extract is the value that appears after "Nifty : "  - in the above ***example '7970.05'***.

I have the following code to extract this:

--code--

```
$('td.text21').each(function () {
                    status = true;
                    var price1 = $(this).text().substr(340,7);
```

--end of code --

however at times I have noticed that the place of the value is not 340 - it changes sometimes to 303 because the img src link changes depending on some values.

***The value will always be after "Nifty : " - this never changes.***

Is there a way where I can ***code to extract the 7 digit value that appears after "Nifty : "***?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of taking the substring from 340, you can take it from the position after where "Nifty :" is, which you get by doing

```
$(this).text().indexOf("Nifty :") + 7; // 7 is the length of "Nifty :"
```

So your new line would be:

```
var price1 = $(this).text().substr($(this).text().indexOf("Nifty :") + 7, 7);
```